# Source is missing in Eclipse for Selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-rc

Please see the attached screenshot.

When I mouse over the following code:

```
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
```

I get this message:

*void com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium.waitForPageToLoad(String arg0)

Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.*

F3 is giving me "*Source not found*".

Does anyone know where to get this source (what is it called) and how do I attach to Eclipse?
[image: ttp://img853.imageshack.us/img853/8248/ecl.png]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

YOu can get the source code through svn here it appears:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/checkout

Once you have downloaded that,

In eclipse, find the jar in 'referenced libraries', right click -> properties

enter the location of the src, in the 'Java Source Attachment' edit box.

Answer (score 6):

The srcs jar is available by downloading the selenium-java-2.x.zip file from the project's download page. For example, the current version (2.0b3) is available here: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-java-2.0b3.zip

You should then be able to attach this as the source for the selenium-java-2.x.jar referenced library.

Comment: thank you as well. but i needed the exact steps how to add the srcs. MeBigFatGuy gave me that answer. but you gave the correct link which was also helpfull :)